# Multiple file upload requests in Angularjs 2 with $q.all() function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a good experience with AngularJS 1 version and I wanted to upgrade to Angularjs 2. Here is my question, does angularjs 2 support similar functionality like $q.all() for multiple HTTP post/get submits?

I tried with forkJoin in angularjs 2 but it doesn`t work as expected. Looking for alternatives. Please suggest if any.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Observable.forkJoin` to send multiple requests on one shot

```
Observable.forkJoin([req1,req2]).subscribe(res=> {
        var firstResult = res[0];
        var secondResult = res[1];
});
```

note that you need to import `Observable` from the `rxjs/Rx`

`import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Either you can use `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all(req1,req2).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```